# Problem with android url matching?

Tags: intentfilter

I have an app which can be opened via browser. I have given intent filter with data scheme http and host as my domain(a.b.com). I'm able to launch my app via browser but thee problem is that if I click on any link in the browser it asks whether to open the activity with my app or browser. How can I make sure that only the link a.b.com opens my app?